Parameter 0 of constructor in required a bean ... that could not be found
In a SpringBatch application I'm developing, I want to make my REST calls from an infra-rest module, but I'm encountering an error concerning bean recognition.
Here is the classes   :
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ContratServiceImpl implements ContratService {
   final ModifierContratOperation modifierContratOperation;
   @Override
    public void updateContrat(String idContrat, ContratSimplifie contrat) {
       try {
          modifierContratOperation.modifierContrat();
           } catch (Exception e) {
              ...
       }
    }

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
   public class ModifierContratOperationImpl implements ModifierContratOperation {
      @Value("${backend.api.url}")
      String backendApiUrl;
      @Override
      public void modifierContrat() {...}

Do any of you know how to correct this error?
I've tried adding a default constructor and scan the component with componentScan annotation but it doesn't solve the problem
